# State not updated in side promise

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, promise, es6-promise

I'm setting state inside promise all and calling a function but inside the function state still shows empty

```js
Promise.all(fileObjs).then((res) => {
     setTradeFilesToUpload(res);
     uploadFiles();
});
```

In Upload function tradefiles shows empty

Comment: why not use another `then` after you're setting your state and there you call your function

Comment: If you're expecting `setTradeFilesToUpload` to change the corresponding local variable (`tradeFilesToUpload`, i'm guessing), it won't. Calling `setTradeFilesToUpload` just asks react to re-render the component. That new render will have its own local variables, but your code from the previous render cannot access them. Why not pass `res` into uploadFiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and try to perform an action that's dependant on that state's value right after it, it will likely run before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why we have `useEffect`, a built-in React hook that activates a callback when one of it's dependencies have changed.

**Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
   uploadFiles()
   // Whatever else we want to do after the state has been updated.
}, [tradeFilesToUpload])
```

The `uploadFiles()` method will run only after the state has finished changing and a render has occurred.

- Note: "tradeFilesToUpload" in the example is interchangeable with whatever other state piece you're dealing with.

Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more info about this.

Comment: **Note:** this is based on the assumption that your original issue was that `uploadFiles()` at some point uses the value of `tradeFilesToUpload` and therefor gets the previous state value.